# Odd error when using Arabic in babel (TeXLive 2019)

Tags: luatex, texlive, babel, arabic

I am facing a weird problem. Files that compiled correctly on earlier versions of `TeXLive` do not work on `TeXLive 2019`. The problem seems to be with `babel` and `arabic` (or a modified persian).

See this example:

```
% !TEX TS-program = LuaLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[arabic]{babel}
\begin{document}
سلام.
\end{document}
```

gives this error:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./x.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>

luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.235 seconds
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/switch.def)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/luababel.def)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/arabi/arabic.ldf
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/luababel.def))
Loading the definitions for the LaTeX{} Arabic encoding
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/arabi/laeenc.def)
Loading the Common definitions for Arabic and Farsi
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/arabi/arabicore.sty
  Arabi Core switching commands v1.0  2006/01/01   (may still change)  
! String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence.
l.137 \ifcase#1\or 
                 ��������� � \ \or �����������^^@�^^@^^@
?
```

Comment: I have tried with LuaLaTeX from TL 2012 to 2019, *always* getting the same error message.

Comment: I’d guess the default font used by lualatex doesn’t contain an Arabic script.

Comment: arabic.ldf is from 2006 and absolutly not usable with lualatex. I don't see why it should ever have been worked with this engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gess your system use the old method with `arabi` that works with `pdflatex`, 
here how to use babel to write arabic with `lualatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bidi=basic-r]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar, main]{arabic}
\babelfont{rm}{Amiri}
\begin{document}
سلام.
\end{document}
```

[image]